# Out of memory when sending large data collections

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration, app-config

I have a product that works fine in most case but then I have one case where I get a lot of out of memory exceptions(on service).

The service is a WCF service hosted as a Windows Service. The service is using netTCPBinding and Protobuf-net to communicate with the Winform clients. Service is set PerCall and uses SessionMode.Required. At the service I keep context objects for the clients to be able to keep track.

The service do also use callbacks.

Both service and client is built as 32 bit so this limits it to use 2 GB ram.

The environment(1000 users) that generates the our of memory exceptions is a lot bigger then the other installations. A thought is that some of the messages is large and that when multiple users request this data at the same time the memory are entirely consumed.

The binding looks like this :

```
<binding name="netTcpRegular" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="01:00:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="1000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="200" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="infinite" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
```

Could the maxBufferSize be the problems?

The Service Throttling is set like this :

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2000" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2000"/>
```

Its possible that also the maxConcurrentCalls is set to high? Maby we should go down to 64?

Rebuild it as a 64 bit software is also a way, this should clear the 2 GB limit of ram.

Comment: A .Net instance run into a out of memory exception at roundabout 1.5 GB without tinkering around. You should consider reducing the amount of data held in memory by your service by queuing requests in a db, only having userIds in memory instead of the whole user object and introducing lazy loading and early unloading of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to build the service in 64 bits and there was no problem with memory limit anymore.

Comment: how could you build a windows service in 64 bits mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to streaming, this is a known issue when sending large payloads with WCF.  The reason for the problem is it tries to load everything into memory before sending the content and after receiving, which is exhausting memory.  See *Large Data Content* section under [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) for info, and **Streaming Data** section to see how to go about to enable streaming

Comment: Yes I have looked in to streaming but it seems like its a entirely different logic, it is not just to change the WCF configuration?

Comment: @SnowJim  Yes, it's a little more involved than modifying the configuration but nothing crazy, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx, other than that, I think your other option is bake some logic into the logic to send data in chunks if possible